# Handle Java plugin exception from C#?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, java-native-interface

e.g.

**Android section**

```html
public class MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  public int divide(int a, int b) throw Exception{
    return a / b;
  }
}
```

**Unity3D section:**

```html
AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
int rlt = jo.Call<int>("divide", new object[](10, 0));
```

Obviously, it'll generate an exception when calling divide(10, 0) in Java. But, can the exception be caught in Unity3D code? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

First of all, `jo.Call<int>("divide", new object[](10, 0));` should not even compile. That should be `jo.Call<int>("divide", new object[] { 10, 0 });`.

> But, can the exception be catched in Unity3D code?

**No**

If there is an exception thrown from the Android native side, your app will be killed.

For example, the code below:

```
AndroidJavaClass jc;
AndroidJavaObject jo;
int rlt;
try
{
    jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    rlt = jo.Call<int>("divide", new object[] { 10, 0 });
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.Log("Error: " + e.Message);
}
```

will only catch an exception if the return type or parameter does not match or even when the `divide` function does not exist at-all.

You have to catch the Exception from the Java side.

```
public int divide(int a, int b)
{
    int result = 0;
    try
    { 
        result = _divide(a, b);
    }catch(Exception e)
                      {
      //...
    }
    return result;
}

public int _divide(int a, int b) throw Exception{
    return a / b;
}
```

You can change the function return type to `string`, catch the exception, convert the exception into a json with `JSONObject` then return result to C# and get each data by using [`JsonUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html)

Comment: Thanks, and further more, which type do you advise to return, a json object or just a string that can be deserialized to a json object? By the way, I have a doubt about AndroidJavaClass. Is it an implementation or an application of JNI? What's the relationship between them? Thanks:)

Comment: I think you should return string **not** the object the use JsonUtility to get the result and error. As for `AndroidJavaClass`, I don't know how it is implemented. Sorry about that